# Rails complete quickly but it takes longer to finish loading the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord, rendering

I've been running with this problem lately. I can spot the following in server console:

`Completed 200 OK in 2748ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 42.8ms)`

As you can see active record and views takes less than a second but still takes around 4 second to get a response from the server. I've run multiple Active record optimization but I can't find why does it take that long to see it.

[image]

Comment: You can install 'ruby-prof' (gem 'ruby-prof') then include this in your view: 
- require 'ruby-prof'
- RubyProf.start
/put your view code here
- result = RubyProf.stop
- printer = RubyProf::CallStackPrinter.new(result)
- file = File.open('profile.html', 'w')
- printer.print(file)
- file.close

You can do it instead on the controller if this doesn't show you anything relevant.
Then open 'profile.html', that will be on the root folder of your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Give [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) a try.

> Middleware that displays speed badge for every html page. Designed to work both in production and in development.

Features:

> Database profiling - Currently supports Mysql2, Postgres, Oracle (oracle_enhanced ~> 1.5.0) and Mongoid3 (with fallback support to ActiveRecord)
>   Call-stack profiling - Flame graphs showing time spent by gem
>   Memory profiling - Per-request memory usage, GC stats, and global allocation metrics